# Jupyter lab keeps turning on simple mode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, settings, jupyter-lab

Whenever I push my jupyter lab window to the side "simple mode" is activated. This results in only one tab displaying and the others get hidden. This is incredibly annoying and I can't believe this is a standard feature (only just installed jupyter lab again). **How do I turn it off? Not just simplemode, but the behaviour of simplemode turning on automatically**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature in JupyterLab 3.0 aimed at improving experience of mobile users. It was certainly not intended to be annoying but I see why it can be.

It toggles the mode if window has less than 760px width, so users with screen size below 1520px will experience what you described when moving window to the side.

The immediate workaround would be to modify the threshold in [lab.ts](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/8456/files#diff-84b6bbef50f946f28304670dea1ab00383a023855aa4170ecb418eaf555713aeR314), changing:

```
const MOBILE_QUERY = 'only screen and (max-width: 760px)';
```

to another threshold, or 0 if you wish to disable completely:

```
const MOBILE_QUERY = 'only screen and (max-width: 0px)';
```

it would require rebuilding lab in dev-mode following steps described in [contributor documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/contributing.html#setting-up-a-local-development-environment).

You can improve your future experience by providing feedback to JupyterLab authors in a related [feedback thread on the community forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/seeking-feedback-jupyterlab-single-document-mode-switch-position/6715). I opened a discussion proposing customization of the threshold [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9567) and you may want to provide more details on your situation (e.g. screen size, browser etc) and consider contributing a solution (probably with some guidance from the current contributors).